# Printing exceptions and error while using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I'm using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor to deploy several tasks parallel.
My project is basing on Selenium.

I want to know when there is an exception during one of the Chrome instances session, and I want to be able to see the exception live during my program is running and that the other instances will continue till they are finish.

Currently, I can't see any of the exceptions and error raising while the program is running and there's a problem in one of the instances.

This is the code for the submit():

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(init, activated_client) for activated_client in activated_clients]
```

I tried few solutions for that, and none of them working for me:

`print(f'{futures.result()}')`

`wait([futures], return_when=FIRST_EXCEPTION)`

```
for future in as_completed([futures]):
    # retrieve the result
    print(future.result())
```

none of the above is working for me.

Any suggestions?